# Making Firefox fullscreen-like without actually maximizing the window

Tags: firefox, fullscreen, cinnamon, manjaro

When using multiple windows on the same monitor, I like to have Firefox and my IDE open side to side (like with Win+Arrow) and it would be cool to have Firefox in a "fullscreen-like" style, where the tab and address bar are temporarily hidden. Is there a way to prevent it from maximizing the window or telling it, to only use half of the actual screen, when pressing F11?

Alternatively, sites like YouTube offer to play a video on full screen. Is there a way, to let single tabs/sites take up the current size of my browser only?

Summarized, I'd like to have the ability to tell a window OR tab, which is switching in "fullscreen" mode, how much of my screen it's actually allowed to take up. For me, tt doesn't matter, if it's a Firefox or Cinnamon setting.

I'm using Firefox 69.0 on a Manjaro Linux with Cinnamon as Desktop.

Comment: What distractions are you trying to get rid off? By default Firefox only has the address bar visible and few other UI elements exposed? Depending on what sites you're viewing "reading mode" might be an option.

Comment: For example when using YouTube, I'd like to just fullscreen the video, so that the content of my window changes and it's current size doesn't. Alternatively hiding tabs and the address bar would be a good start, but on youtube, there would still be the search bar, recommendations, etc.

Comment: Which doesn't change by pressing F11. You don't seem to have a good idea of what you actually want. The full screen function of most video sites is very different from a distraction free mode. Pressing F11 as well. The mentioned reading mode would give you an option for sites that support it. On Windows using Win+Cursor Buttons you can move the window around and also make it use 50% of your screen. Something similar is probably available on Linux. Hiding the tab bar [is possible](https://superuser.com/questions/1268732/how-to-hide-tab-bar-tabstrip-in-firefox-57-quantum).

Comment: Please refine your question instead of leaving those details in the comments.

Comment: I think I have the same question, let me rephrase please: I have a 4k monitor and want to have 4 browser windows equally split on one screen. Windows can do that, however, the tab bar and URL line are a bit annoying. I know it is pretty nit picky but it would be great if someone knows how to do that

Comment: This is perfect for users of 32:9 super-ultrawide monitors that don't want to fiddle with two displayport cables and faffing around in the OSD to switch to "Picture by Picture Mode" or whatever they choose to call it.

Answer (score 11):

Was looking for the same thing and after a bit of digging I learned that this can be achieved by setting `full-screen-api.ignore-widgets` to `true` in `about:config`. After setting this, the full screen hotkey/button will trigger fullscreen like normal, except it won't resize the window. This allows you to have several applications open on a single monitor along side a "pseudo fullscreen" firefox.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for something similar, it was not exactly what i was looking for but i think it provides what you want.

**Unfortunataly the first solution is removed in** `Firefox Nightly 86.0a1`

Firstly, the source for this information is [here](https://techdows.com/2020/03/firefox-install-websites-as-apps-like-chrome.html).
The main idea is to use a web site like an App, so the browser toolbars are not visible in this mode.

I will be copying the instructions from the source to make them permanent here.

### Install a website as an App in the Firefox browser

1. To get started, download and install [Firefox Nightly](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/nightly/all/) on your computer, and launch it
2. Load `about:config` and create a Boolean Pref named `browser.ssb.enabled` and choose its value as `true`.
3. Restart Firefox and visit any website in the address bar, click on … icon to open the Page Action menu and select `Use this site in App mode`.
   Example [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGmXi.png).

Tip: You can right-click and add that icon to address bar so that, next time, you can install apps more easily by clicking on that icon.

4. The website’s shortcut will be created on the desktop and that site will open in a window with site favicon without any toolbars, browser chrome, and navigational elements when launched. Example [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ke0cI.png).

### Uninstalling Apps in Firefox browser

1. In the Firefox browser, click on the hamburger menu icon to open the menu,
2. Select Sites in App Mode, click on close icon at the end of a website title, that app will be uninstalled. Example [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85NBs.png).

### Starting from Firefox version 73 Nightly

This kind of shortcut seems to let you easily launch the website in "Site Specific Browser" mode directly:

`"C:\Program Files\Firefox Nightly\firefox.exe" --ssb https://www.google.com`

### Edit: A modern solution in form of an extension (and a helper userscript if necessary) that currently works

[This](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/windowed/) extension lets you to choose between several modes for a web page that supports "Fullscreen" modes. You can either choose "Windowed" (probably the one you want), "In-window" (the one i wanted), "PiP" (Picture-in-Picture) and regular "Fullscreen" mode.

If a page does not support any form of FullScreen toggle, a userscript like [this](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/29200-f11-for-fullscreen/code) can help. In this userscript

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
        var key = event.which || event.keyCode;
        if (key == 122 && document.fullscreenEnabled){
            if (!document.fullscreenElement)
                document.documentElement.requestFullscreen();
            else if (document.exitFullscreen)
                document.exitFullscreen();
        }
    });
})();
```

`key == 122` part can be replaced to have another button as shortcut. Key codes for keyboard buttons can be found in tools like https://keycode.info/. Pressing the shortcut pops up the extensions menu like `https://i.imgur.com/aFETyxw.png`. You can choose "In-window" here to have your web page in a standalone window without any toolbars.