# Is it possible to show a window in "fullscreen mode" in a Windows 11 dock area?

Tags: windows-11, window, fullscreen

Docking windows to Windows 11 dock areas works well, but the window remains in its normal state, showing the menu bar etc.

Is it possible to activate the fullscreen mode (<kbd>F11</kbd>) of a window, by restricting it to a Windows 11 dock area?

This question is about the same, but for Firefox only:
[Making Firefox fullscreen-like without actually maximizing the window](https://superuser.com/questions/1483037/making-firefox-fullscreen-like-without-actually-maximizing-the-window)