# Show Firefox min/max/close button when tab bar is hidden

Tags: firefox

I have tabs in side bar so I removed the Firefox upper tab bar using userChrome.css:

```
#TabsToolbar { 
    visibility: collapse !important; 
}
```

This also caused min/max/close buttons to disappear from the title bar.

How can I bring them back?

Comment: I posted a solution in another thread: https://superuser.com/questions/1268732/how-to-hide-tab-bar-tabstrip-in-firefox-57-quantum/1819514#1819514

Answer (score 1):

I haven't been able to find a way to do this through CSS - probably because I'm not great at CSS - but one way to accomplish this is to download the "minimize window" extension by andyye and the "Close Window Button" extension by jingyu9575. This will put a minimize button and a close window button to the right of the URL bar. I haven't found a reliable extension for the maximize window button so I don't have anything to help there. Personally I just always use the Win+up shortcut to maximize so it hasn't been an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Go to View->Toolbars->Customize Toolbar, then check the "Title Bar" box at the bottom

After doing that and hiding the tab toolbar in userChrome.css, you should see no tab bar but still have the menu buttons